# Trying to show user id - showing as 0

Tags: php, mysql

Logging in:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$id = mysql_query("SELECT  `id`  FROM  `users` WHERE `username`='" . $username . "'");
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Index ( trying to display it here)

```
Welcome, <?= $username ?><br> ((works))
ID: <?= $id ?>
```

The id simply displays as 0 when in reality it is 1.

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` shouldn't be used in new code because it's been deprecated, is dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a number of recommendations as to how to keep your application up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query()` returns a resource id, not the results of your query. You need to use [**`mysql_fetch_assoc()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [**`mysql_result()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) to get your value:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT  `id`  FROM  `users` WHERE `username`='" . $username . "'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$id = $result['id'];
```

or

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT  `id`  FROM  `users` WHERE `username`='" . $username . "'");
$id = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

There are other ways to do it but this shows you where your general error occurs.

Comment: doh, thanks for the quick answer; working on a lot of projects today and need to get things done.